# Methods to style HTML mail

Tags: html, css, email

I've heard from other sources that the only way you could possibly style the HTML content in an HTML mail is by using inline styles (which is grossly inconvenient).  Is there another method to style HTML in HTML mail such that it works on all mailing platforms (e.g. Gmail)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your other sources are correct. External stylesheets are not supported by many major webmail clients. Even if you're using inline css, it's advised to use the bare minimu due to the spam-sensitivity that over-using css can cause apparently.

Reference: http://templates.mailchimp.com/development/css/

You might want to look into: http://foundation.zurb.com/emails